# Create socket when have DNS name

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

Bellow is peace of code that I use to connect to socket in Windows. Sometimes I don't have IP dress, but have DNS name in `inetAddr`. Probably I must resolve address from host name, or it is possible create socket with `DNS` name? What is the best way to create socket when have `DNS` name?

```
commStatus communicate( const char * tx, char * rx, const int bufSize , const char * inetAddr, const int port )
{
...
        SOCKET s;
        struct sockaddr_in server;


        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inetAddr);
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons( port );

        if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {

            FILELOGL("Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError(),Level::Error );

        } else
        {
            if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
            {
                FILELOGL("connect error", Level::Error);
                r= commStatus::COMM_NO_TRANSMIT ;
            } else
            {
            ...
            }
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Resolve it, dear Liza.

Comment: @MartinJames With what shall I resolve it, dear Henry?

Comment: @IronSavior: Did you read the answers that were already provided before you posted that comment?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not mad, but I'm disappointed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket

Answer (score 2):

There is only one way: Resolve the host name.

Here's a part of my code that I've modified and haven't tested, but it should work:

```
WSADATA wsdata;

const char * inetAddr

addrinfo hints, *res;

WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsdata);

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol   = IPPROTO_TCP;

if (getaddrinfo("someaddress.com", NULL, &hints, &res) != 0)
    return false;

inetAddr = inet_ntoa(((sockaddr_in *) res -> ai_addr) -> sin_addr);
```

Comment: If you use `getaddrinfo()` with `AF_UNSPEC`, it can return either an IPv4 or IPv6 address, so you have to delay calling `socket()` until you know what type of socket to create, either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`. Otherwise, if you create the socket first, you have to set `hints.ai_family` to match the socket family actually used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, this is correct, but anyway, you have to call `getaddrinfo` before you create the socket, because he says that `inetAddr` is sometimes an ip or sometimes a DNS name, and then it doesn't matter if the protocol is IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: And also because a DNS lookup can report multiple IPs, so you have to try all of them until one succeeds.  See my answer for an example of doing that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just wrote code that is easy to understand and not fully developed, yes sure DNS lookup can output multiple IPs, but what do you want to reach with your comments? I post an answer and you post an answer, and he can choose what he accepts, in addition this code worked for me all the time.

Comment: The code you have shown is incomplete. It does not allow the caller to specify an IP address instead of a DNS hostname. And your use of `inet_ntoa()` assumes `res->ai_addr` is IPv4 but it might be IPv6 instead because you are using `AF_UNSPEC` instead of `AF_INET` in `hints.ai_family`. When converting an IP address to a string, you have to check the address's family field, or else use `getnameinfo()` with the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag (or other equivalent function) and let it figure out how to format the address into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the DNS name.  Use [`getaddrinfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx) for that.  Just note that a DNS name can resolve to multiple IPs, both IPv4 and IPv6, so you have to call `getaddrinfo()` first in order to know how many IPs are reported, and what type of socket to create for each IP.

For example:

```
commStatus communicate( const char * tx, char * rx, const int bufSize , const char * inetAddr, const int port )
{
    ...
    SOCKET s = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo hint = {0};
    hint.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hint.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    struct addrinfo *addrs = NULL;
    int ret = getaddrinfo(inetAddr, NULL, &hint, &addrs);
    if (ret == EAI_NONAME)
    {
        hint.ai_flags = 0;
        ret = getaddrinfo(inetAddr, NULL, &hint, &addrs);
    }

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        FILELOGL("Could not resolve inetAddr: " << ret, Level::Error);
    }
    else
    {
        for (struct addrinfo *addr = addrs; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
        {
            s = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
            if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                FILELOGL("Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError(), Level::Error);
                break;
            }

            if (connect(s, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen) == 0)
                break;

            closesocket(s);
            s = INVALID_SOCKET;

            if (addr->ai_next == NULL)
            {
                FILELOGL("connect error", Level::Error);
            }
        }

        freeaddrinfo(addrs);

        if (s != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```